# How to convolve a Unit function (like "UnitTriangle") with a InterpolatedFunction

Tags: interpolation

Recently discovered what `InterpolatingFunction`'s are in *Mathematica*...really amazing/useful. As I understand it, it's basically a curve fitter....sorta.

So how would I use *Convolve* with a unit triangle or some other analytical-esque function, to convolve over a *InterpolatingFunction*??

[image]

In the image, the red triangle is `UnitTriangle[x]` (well, it's height and width are off, but you get the gist of it). So ideallly, I'd like to do something like 
`Convolve[ UnitTriangle[x], InterpolatedFunction, ?, ?]`

But that won't work of course, since I don't know what the domains are (hence the ? ?) for the interpolated function.

Comment: I think `Convolve` works only symbolically.  You might have to use `NIntegrate` to do the convolution integral directly.

Comment: Yes, as Michael said you need to integrate numerically.  Not only does `Convolve` require symbolic input, it also integrates over the whole real line, which won't work for an interpolating function with a restricted domain.

Comment: Hmm. Well, if you use NIntegrate you just get a number out right? Is there a way, for example, to use NIntegreate to get the same graph output, as this would do -->      Convolve[UnitBox[x], UnitBox[x], x, t]     Really I just need the graph output of what the convolution of the unit triangle with an interpolation function would look like.

Comment: If you specifically want to use `Convolve`, you have to construct a different kind of interpolation function to work with. For instance, you can use `Piecewise`, `InterpolatingPolynomial` or construct the function using your own basis functions. I must say I'm a bit saddened by the fact `Interpolation`, `BezierFunction` and `BSPlineFunction` don't produce suitable output, but instead you have to trouble yourself to get all this done.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to stop you from using `NIntegrate` with a parameter and have it evaluated for a given value of that parameter, e.g.

```
Plot[ NIntegrate[ f[x] UnitTriangle[ x - x0], {x, 1, 6}], {x0, 1, 6}]
```

Now, this is somewhat slow and can be made significantly faster by telling NIntegrate not to bother with any symbolic preprocessing:

```
 Plot[ NIntegrate[ f[x] UnitTriangle[ x - x0], {x, 1, 6}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {x0, 1, 6}]
```